# fabric how did it to work and using sudo (connection class) method?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

Am like to figure out in Fabric https://www.fabfile.org/index.html , framework to run commands on the remote machine via SSH.

Via Getting Started, I could do to connect, running commands via user with connected by; and run commands with sudo by the Responder.

But I ran into problem, that I need to run utility, which requires password after root/sudo password - it utility sqlcmd, it CLI-client to MSSQL database and i have password authentication there. A tried add second Responder, but it doesn't work. Also i have did forget why i wasn't using -P option for sqlcmd.

So, I wanted to use sudo method of Connection, but cannot find where to specify password for sudo.

thats example am partially work. Error screen presents.

```
import getpass
from fabric import Connection, Config
import fabric.config
import paramiko
import getpass

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


c = Connection(host = '93.156.248.1', user = 'nnnnn'
    , connect_kwargs={ "password": "1234"}
   #, config=config
    )

c.run('ls -a') #this works

c.sudo('iostat', kwargs={ "password": "H9!nrsnrsnrs"}) #this not works

c.close()
```

what's problem? Please help.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHwoq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import getpass
from fabric import Connection, Config
import fabric.config
import paramiko
import getpass

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

sudo_pass = "1234"

config = Config(overrides={'sudo': {'password': sudo_pass}})

c = Connection(host = '93.156.228.8', user = 'nrv'
    , connect_kwargs={ "password": "123"} 
    , config=config
    )

c.run('ls -a')

c.sudo('iostat')
```

this works, problem that is not written in doc, wherefor i seen then and tried in my code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).